# Error: spawn EACCES in ubuntu for node.js/express app trying to run python

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, ubuntu, express

I have made a node.js server to run a python script using [python-shell](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell)  and am encountering an EACCES error ever since migrating from windows to Ubuntu. I have to my knowledge and limited ability tried to set the correct permissions to no avail, and have not currently found anyone with a problem such as this with a server trying to run another script. My question is how do I stop such an error occuring?

EDIT: Added JavaScript code, Image of ls-l in main server folder, and js script folder.

Express HTML error log (modified):

```
<h1>spawn EACCES</h1>
<h2></h2>
<pre>Error: spawn EACCES
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:298:11)
    at exports.spawn (child_process.js:362:9)
    at new PythonShell (/home/user_name/simple_server/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:59:25)
    at run_py_script (/home/user_name/simple_server/routes/rain_track.js:11:19)
    at /home/user_name/simple_server/routes/rain_track.js:43:5
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/user_name/simple_server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/user_name/simple_server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/user_name/simple_server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/user_name/simple_server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)</pre>
```

Javascript code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

var options = {
    mode: 'json',
    pythonPath: '/home/user_name/simple_server'
};

function run_py_script(data, res, callback){
    var pyshell = new PythonShell('dummy.py', options);
    console.log(data.latitude + ", " + data.longitude + "\n");
    pyshell.send(""+data.latitude + ", "+ data.longitude+"\n"); // change to data

    pyshell.on('message', function(message){
        console.log(message);
        res.json(message);
    });

    pyshell.end(function(err){
        if (err) {
            console.log("Python script error has occured.");
            console.log(err);
        }
        //return err ? callback(null) : callback(null, ret_val);
    });
}

/* GET rain_track data. */

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Location got: "+req.body.coords.latitude + ", " + req.body.coords.longitude);
    var location_data = {
        "latitude" : req.body.coords.latitude,
        "longitude" : req.body.coords.longitude
    };
    run_py_script(location_data, res, function(err, rain_data) {
        if (err){ console.log("error in python script" ); return res.json(null); }
    })
});
module.exports = router;
```

`ls -l`:

[image: ls -l of directories]

Comment: Can you post the relevant code where you're trying to run the python script? Also, some `ls -l` output from the relevant directories might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Upon detailed testing I have been unable to find a solution to this issue, and the question has indeed died.

However I successfully found a work-around, finding the issue with the EACCES was with the python path (in the options object). Removing this and running a python script in the server terminal's run location (e.g. `/bin` directory) would still work fine.